# Adding Links in PowerPoint Slides from a Delphi Application

Tags: delphi, hyperlink, powerpoint

I've got some code in a Delphi (version 10.3) program that opens and makes some updates to an existing PowerPoint presentation.  I got everything working except that I would like to create a table of contents with links to other slides, and I haven't been able to find out how to add links.  It's using the PowerPoint2010 and Office 2010 units.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
{ Add header slide }
FinalDeck.Slides.Add(1, 2);
SlideOb := FinalDeck.Slides.Item(1);
for Index := 1 to SlideOb.Shapes.Count do
begin
  ShapeOb := SlideOb.Shapes.Item(Index);
  if (ShapeOb.HasTextFrame = msoTrue) then
  begin
    if (Index = 1) then
      Shapeob.TextFrame.TextRange.Text := 'Table of Contents';
    if (Index = 2) then
    begin
      TempSt := 'Section 1' + #13#10 + 'Section 2' + #13#10; + 'Section 3'
      ShapeOb.TextFrame.TextRange.Text := TempSt;
    end;
  end;
end;  { of: for Index }
```

So, the idea would be to add links where it says "Section 1", "Section 2", etc., to the appropriate slides, if possible.  I'm also open to a different approach, if there's a better/easier way.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to success is to append text ranges to `TextFrame` one by one and configure their [hyperlinks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.hyperlink). To configure hyperlink to a slide within the presentation you set its:

1. [`Address`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.hyperlink.address) property to an empty string (this is empty by default)
2. [`SubAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.hyperlink.subaddress) property to a value in format `{SlideID},{SlideIndex},{SlideTitle}`. See [here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?47962-How-can-you-name-a-slide-and-then-refer-to-it-by-name-in-a-hyperlink) for further information.

Use `TextRange.ActionSettings.Item(ppMouseClick).Hyperlink` to access hyperlink of a text range.

Check out this sample code that creates new presentation with opening slide followed by ToC slide and 3 section slides.

```
procedure CreatePresentation(const FileName: string);
var
  App: PowerPointApplication;
  Presentation: PowerPointPresentation;
  SlideTOC, SlideSection: PowerPointSlide;
  FrameTOC: TextFrame;
  RangeHyperlink: TextRange;
  SectionIndex: Integer;
  SectionTitle: string;
begin
  App := CoPowerPointApplication.Create;
  try
    Presentation := App.Presentations.Add(msoFalse);
    { Insert opening slide }
    Presentation.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitle).Shapes.Item(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text := 'The Presentation';
    { Insert table of contents }
    SlideTOC := Presentation.Slides.Add(2, ppLayoutObject);
    SlideTOC.Shapes.Item(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text := 'Table of Contents';
    FrameTOC := SlideTOC.Shapes.Item(2).TextFrame;
    { Insert section slides }
    for SectionIndex := 1 to 3 do
    begin
      SectionTitle := 'Section ' + IntToStr(SectionIndex);
      SlideSection := Presentation.Slides.Add(Presentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutObject);
      SlideSection.Shapes.Item(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text := SectionTitle;
      RangeHyperlink := FrameTOC.TextRange.InsertAfter(SectionTitle + sLineBreak);
      RangeHyperlink.ActionSettings.Item(ppMouseClick).Hyperlink.SubAddress :=
        IntToStr(SlideSection.SlideID) + ',' + IntToStr(SlideSection.SlideIndex) + ',' + SectionTitle;
    end;
    Presentation.SaveAs(FileName, ppSaveAsPresentation, msoFalse);
    Presentation.Close;
  finally
    App.Quit;
  end;
end;
```

To apply that to your use case you need to know `SlideID` or index of the target slide. Notice the use of `FrameTOC.TextRange.InsertAfter` in the loop to append the hyperlinks to the text frame of table of contents.

Comment: This did the trick, Peter.  Thanks so much.